# Question on number theory ( related to (Z/p^rZ)* group )

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

This is a (different version to) question from Serre 'A Course in Arithmetic'.Let p be an odd prime number. $\forall n\geq 1$ (n positive integer), $f$ is defined by:
$$f(n)=(-1)^n\prod_{1\le k\le n ,(p,k)=1} k$$
I wish to show: $$f(p^r)  \equiv 1\mod{p^r} \space\space\space\space\space \space((\mathbb{Z}/p^r\mathbb{Z})^\times)$$
**and**  prove that f can be expanded to continuous function
 $f: \mathbb{Zp} \to  \mathbb{Zp} $  , Such that $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |x-y| $.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Look in any book on $p$-adic analysis that discusses the  $p$-adic Gamma function (e.g., texts by Koblitz or Robert).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a group $G$ (in this case $G = (\mathbb{Z}/p^r\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$). Then $\prod_ {g^2 \neq 1} g = 1$ (rearrange the sum to pair an element with its inverse).

It follows $$\prod_ {g\in G} g = \prod_ {g^2 = 1} g.$$

If $p \geq 2,$ then $(\mathbb{Z}/p^r\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is cyclic and $-1$ is the only two torsion element. One concludes

$$f(p^r) \equiv (-1)^{p^r} (-1) \mod p^r \equiv 1 \mod p^r.$$